# "Invalid format string" error when parsing date string with Timex in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to Elixir.

I'm having trouble getting date parsing to work in with Timex, so I decided to copy a line out of its test suite and run it in iex, and even that doesn't succeed.

The parse call below was copied from https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/master/test/parse_strftime_test.exs and just modified by prefixing the Timex module name.

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.2.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> use Timex
nil
iex(2)> Timex.parse("20150713 14:01:21.053021", "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
{:error,
 {:format, "Invalid format string, must contain at least one directive."}}
```

I'm assuming the test suite runs fine, but as an incidental question to solving my date parsing problem, I'd like to learn how to run the test suite for my installed dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the [tests](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/8fc02c16d779b542aae60df4081a4f547fc9d119/test/parse_strftime_test.exs#L29), you need to pass `:strftime` as the third argument to `Timex.parse/3` if you want to use `strftime` like format.

```
iex(1)> Timex.parse("20150713 14:01:21.053021", "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f", :strftime)
{:ok, #<DateTime(2015-07-13T14:01:21Z)>}
```

Comment: I don't see any functions actually passing `:strftime` in calls to parse on that page though? Looks like they're all calls to Timex.parse/2?

Comment: Baugh, somehow I'd missed that the `defp parse/2` in the test was calling `Timex.parse/3`. Thanks!